# How to store a file inside an executable

Tags: c++, c, file, executable

I was wondering if it is possible to store for example an image or other file inside an executable and then work with that at runtime (for example showing the image on the screen).

I know auto-extractable archives exists and I also wonder how those work.

Finally, how can it be implemented using C/C++?

I'm working in a windows 10 x64 enviroment but I'm also interested in the linux enviroment

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Why storing "inside an exe", why not in as a separate file?

Comment: @Brainless Just curious to explore this approach to store/share files

Comment: @Brainless I'd seconds that. You could use them inside you "*.exe" as resource and work with that. In VS you can create Ressource- files by right clicking you project and go to "add" and add a ressource file. Theres much more info on the interwebz for that.

Comment: Adding your OS environment might be useful.

Comment: [Here's a linux/mingw way](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/linking-a-binary-blob-with-gcc/) to do it.

Comment: On what platform? Windows has resources which can be tacked on afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Files are just arrays of bytes. So, to contain a file within an executable, you simply need an array that contains the bytes of the file:

```
unsigned char file_content[] = {
  0x23, 0x20, 0x46, 0x6c, ...
};
```

Tools exist to generate such declaration from an input file (`xxd -i`). It's also fairly trivial to write such tool yourself.

Another technique is to embed the file at linking stage. Drawback of this approach is that it is highly toolchain specific.

---

However, do consider that reading a separate file at runtime is usually simpler and provides more flexibility.

---

There is also a proposal to add standard function to do this [P1040R4](https://thephd.github.io/vendor/future_cxx/papers/d1040.html), which may be available in a future C++ standard

Comment: I didn't know about `xxd -i`! You're right, it is rather trivial, but still a nice *nix command to know!

Answer (score 0):

Embedded resources are very common, and part of the PE file format. If you're using Visual Studio for example, you can add any binary data you want as a resource. It will be compiled using `rc.exe`, the resource compiler, and linked into the output binary.

You access these resources with the `FindResource`, `LoadResource`, and `LockResource` winapi calls.